# How can I implement a program that scrolls a string, and for each ocurrence of a letter place the ocurrence in uppercase?

Tags: java, char, uppercase

What I need to do is to Implement a program that receives a string A and any letter t.
Scroll through each character of the string and for each occurrence of the letter of
t entry, place in uppercase each occurrence in the string.

Then I did this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.Character;
/**
 *
 * @author Santiago
 */
public class LecturaCaracteres {
        public static void main(String args[])
            {
                String A=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la palabra");
   char s[]=A.toCharArray();   
   for(int i=0; i< s.length; i++ )
   {
      s[i]=(char) i;      
      String t="t";      
       if (s.equals(t)) {          
          s.toUpperCase();          
          System.out.println(s);
       }        
    }      
   }    
}
```

If anyone can help me with this, I will be grateful.

Comment: What help do you need? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: `s[i]=(char) i;` this doesn't seem right.

Comment: And I guess [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)) is out of the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s[i]=(char) i;
```

this sentence will change s[i] with special symbol...so i am not clear that what you want to
do.

you want change 't' to 'T'??or spread with 't'??

```
 String A=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la palabra");
   char s[]=A.toCharArray();   
   for(int i=0; i< s.length; i++ )
   {

      char t='t';      
       if (s[i]==t) 
       {          
          s[i]='T';          

       }        
   } 
   System.out.println(s);
```

Luke’s answer may be more better~~
Sorry,my English is not good.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String A=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la palabra");
    String s = A.replace("t","T");
    System.out.println(s);
```

This will get the job done far simpler.

I would recommend a bit better name convention for your variables however, if anyone else has to read your code later it could be difficult. (Or you could be like me and just forget.)

Generally best to keep capitals for Class names, while you set variables and methods like so:
variableName, methodName(). This helps you keep an easy to use and remember standard.